# image rotates in opposite direction after i flip image vertically or horizontally

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uigesturerecognizer, image-rotation

problem with rotating image after flipping image to vertical or horizontal.
I am just changing scale of image on vertical & horizontal flip-button click.

**for vertical flip image m using code:-**

```
imageView_Tattoo.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);//flips image to up
imageView_Tattoo.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);//flips image to down
```

**for horizontal flip image:-**

```
imageView_Tattoo.transform = CGAffineTransformMake( -1, 0, 0, 1, 0,1);//flips image to left
imageView_Tattoo.transform = CGAffineTransformMake( 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,0);//flips image to left
```

**for rotation in self.view:-**

```
//Rotates img speedily
     CGFloat mTotalRotation = 0.0;
    if ([rotationRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) 
    {
        mTotalRotation += rotationRecognizer.rotation;
        return;
    }

    imageView_Tattoo.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(imageView_Tattoo.transform, rotationRecognizer.rotation);
```

In the above rotation code whenever i try to rotate image its rotating speedily.

& if else i use any other code to rotate my image such as:-

```
CGFloat angle = rotationRecognizer.rotation;
imageView_Tattoo.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(imageView_Tattoo.transform, angle);
rotationRecognizer.rotation = 0.0;
```

the image rotate perfectly but, after fliping the image the image rotates in opposite direction.

Any type of help is appreciated....... Thanking you